# Avoid changing select tag after first change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider that I have the following select tag:

```
<select id="select_val">
<option>This is first</option>
<option>This is second</option>
</select>
```

Now what I want is , I want the select to be present however we should not be able to change it further.
e.g if he selects option two i.e This is second, he cannot change it further. How can i do that using jquery. Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean it will be disabled only if the second option is selected? or you want it to be disabled irrespective of what option is selected?

Comment: I meant as soon as it is selected, it should be disabled ,option 2 was just an example. I am new on Stack overflow hence might have been bit unclear in my questioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#select_val').change(function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
})
```

**Edit after comment:**

If You want pass selected value and keep selection disabled, there are several solutions. Now it depends if You use AJAX or just simple form submit.
For AJAX You can do it like that:

```
$('form').submit(functiom(){
    $('#select_val').prop('disabled', false);
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $('#select_val').prop('disabled', true);

    $.ajax({
        url : 'some_url',
        data : data
        // ... other parameters here
    });
});
```

If it's simple form submit then I wouldn't toggle disabled to off as user can stop sending form by pressing escape key and then change selection. Then another approach could be create hidden input like:

```
$('form').submit(functiom(){
    var select = $('#select_val');
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="'+ select[0].name +'" value="'+ select.val() +'">');
});
```

Comment: Plain and simple, Thanks. I don't know why someone downvoted the answer. :)

Comment: I came across a fault in this, even though it freezes further selections,if suppose you have a form and want to submit this as one of the parameters , it won't work simply because its disabled.So a solution in which I cannot change the value still it can be passed as a parameter would be great

Comment: @user3103915 oh right, forgot about that. See my edit